# Erro no Upload de Imagem em PHP

Tags: php

Estou obtendo o erro abaixo quando faço o upload de uma imagem, porém não estou conseguindo identificar o que tenho que corrigir.

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/uploads/1432585475.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/storage/b/71/d0/site1390582818/public_html/upimgsc.php on line 40

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/home/storage/b/71/d0/site1390582818/tmp/php0CABDK' to '/uploads/1432585475.png' in /home/storage/b/71/d0/site1390582818/public_html/upimgsc.php on line 40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, aparentemente o erro diz que essa pasta `/uploads` não está sendo encontrada.

**No such file or directory**

A pasta `/uploads` existe mesmo ? Essa pasta fica na raiz ?

Comment: Olá Diego.... sim, está na raiz!

Answer (score 3):

Antes de upar sua imagem, crie o diretório caso não existir.

Depois do código verificando você pode fazer o upload.

```
$folder = 'seu/diretorio/uploads';
if (!is_dir($folder)) {
    mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O `move_uploaded_file()` precisa de 2 argumentos.

O destino temporário do ficheiro (que é defenido no PHP.ini como diretoria temporária para uploads) e o destino final, indicado por ti.

Nota que essa diretoria já tem de existir. Se não existir ainda (e com as permissões certas) tens de a criar. Podes criar a diretoria [como o @Diego sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/65895/129).

```
$temp  = $_FILES["new_image"]["tmp_name"];
$error = $_FILES["new_image"]["error"];

if ($error > 0) die("Algo correu mal!... code $error.");
move_uploaded_file($temp, $finalPath); // $finalPath defenida por tí
```

Tem em mente que não é seguro colocar ficheiros que vieram por upload disponiveis dentro de `public_html`. Pelo menos verifica se o ficheiro é uma imagem assim:

```
$temp  = $_FILES["new_image"]["tmp_name"];
$error = $_FILES["new_image"]["error"];
$name =  $_FILES["new_image"]["name"];

$uploadPath = "/home/storage/b/71/d0/site1390582818/upload/".$name;
$finalPath  = "/home/storage/b/71/d0/site1390582818/public_html/upload/".$name;

if ($error > 0) die("Algo correu mal!... code $error.");
move_uploaded_file($temp, $uploadPath);

$size = getimagesize($uploadPath);
if(!$size) die('Algo correu mal!...');
rename($uploadPath, $finalPath);
```

Comment: O upload deu certo, porém no campo "foto" da tabela...estou gravando o

Comment: @Valloto como assim no no campo "foto" da tabela? podes explicar melhor?

Comment: Estou gravando o caminho e o nome da imagem, na tabela imagem.. na coluna foto! Ficando da seguinte forma ' caminho/imagem.png '

Comment: @Valloto "tabela" e "coluna" usa-se em bases de dados tipo MySQL, é isso que estás a falar? ou queres dizer pasta/arquivo? no caso de ser pasta/arquivo podes mudar o caminho que queres nas variáveis `$finalPath` e `$uploadPath` e o código vai fazer o que queres.

Comment: Consegui fazer a gravação e visualizar também as imagens, o código acabou ficando de forma bem simples, vou concluir o serviço e posto o código pra vocês me ajudarem com padrões. Obrigado